# Convert String with Underscores to .Net Enum with Standard Naming Convention

Tags: c#, .net, enums, json.net, json-deserialization

How do I use Json.Net to convert:

```
{ "key": "an_ugly_value" }
```

To this:

```
enum Key
{
  AnUglyValue
}
```

Pseudo-code to further illustrate problem:

```
...
class AnObject
{
  public Key Key { get; set; }
}

var anObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnObject>("{ \"key\": \"an_ugly_value\" }");

assert(anObject.Key == Key.AnUglyValue);
...
```

Thanks to whoever linked to the above answer. Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate the solution:

```
enum Key
{
  [Description("an_ugly_value")]
  AnUglyValue
}

public class KeyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Key);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var keyMember = typeof(Key).GetMembers()
                                   .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)).Any())
                                   .FirstOrDefault(x => ((DescriptionAttribute)x.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute))).Description == (string)reader.Value);

        return keyMember == null ? Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), (string)reader.Value) : Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), keyMember.Name);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var anObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnObject>("{ \"key\": \"an_ugly_value\" }", new KeyConverter());
```

Comment: do a google search on how to convert a json string || json array to an enum

Comment: That's not helpful. I've added pseudo-code to try to make my question more clear.

Comment: It's not about clearness, it's about showing some effort.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "clarity".

Comment: See [no. 5](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clearness?s=t). And by the way, _this_ was a perfect example of _effort_.

Comment: Deserializing seems straightforward but re-serializing seems awkward.  Would you want to replace all capital letters in the enum name to "_s"?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. Voted to reopen

Comment: I was able to use the linked question and accepted answer to get things working. I'll edit with an illustration.

Comment: Just as I just finished the converter